# Simple way to find out how many Crossfilter dimensions currently exist?

Tags: crossfilter, dc.js

I have a lot of dynamic views and dynamically created Crossfilter dimensions. I often exceed the limit of 32. So I've been disposing of them as new ones are created, but it's actually difficult to consistently keep track of them. It would helpful during development to get a list of all crossfilter dimensions or at least the number of them.

(Just to be clear, I'm not asking about the number of records, crossfilter.size())

thanks!

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an API function for this, but you could simply keep track of how many times you call `.dimension()`.

Comment: Yah, I think you'll need to roll your own - perhaps by pushing them onto an array.

Answer (score 0):

Good suggestions. I essentially ended up doing that and it's working well.

To show the total number of dimensions:

```
_.size(measureDimensions)
```

But more importantly, consolidating them in an object allowed me to reference and dispose of them easily:

```
var measureDimensions = {};
var measureGroups = {};
var measureCharts = {};


function generateCharts(entities) {
    _.each(entities, function(entity){
        // attach the charts to the following elements:
        $('.js-measures-container').append('<div class="aligned-barchart" id="dc-'+entity'">')

        // create dimensions and groups
        measureDimensions[entity] = xf.dimension(function(d){ return d[entity] });
        measureGroups[entity] = measureDimensions[entity].group().reduceCount();

        // output the number of dimensions:
        console.log('total dimensions: ', _.size(measureDimensions))

        // generate chart
        measureCharts[entity] = dc.barChart('#dc-'+entity)
            .width(_.span(10))
            .height(40)
            .dimension(measureDimensions[entity])
            .group(measureGroups[entity])
            // etc...
    })
};

// Code called by event handler that requires dimensions to be disposed:
function cleanup() {
    _.each(measureDimensions, function(dim){ dim.dispose() });
    _.each(measureGroups, function(group){ group.dispose() });
    measureDimensions = {};
    measureGroups = {};
    measureCharts = {};
};
```

(I'm using [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org), but all this could be done with vanilla JS)